# Lengthy numbers type A : remove all occurrences of length

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Given a non negative integer number tell if it can be erased by repeatedly removing **all** occurrences of the length of that number from it **including overlapping matches**.

- Erasing means cancel all its digits.
  For example the number *4440* is not lengthy because after removing all 4's you obtain *0* which cannot be erased.
  Neither the number *50022* or *50044* is lengthy A because you first remove 5 obtaining *0022* or *0044* and there's no way to cancel leading 0's.

**Examples**

```
3610106336 has 10 digits: remove 10's
36xxXX6336 -> 366336

366336 has 6 digits: remove 6's
3xx33x -> 333

333 remove 3's -> erased
```

Here an example with **overlapping matches**.

```
11111666661 has 11 digits

xxXX1666661  \ overlapping 11's
1XXxx666661  / 
We have 5 '1' for a total of 4 '11' matched, remove all


666661  -> remove 6's
1 -> and finally 1
```

## Test cases

Truthy

```
1, 12, 21, 22, 123, 321, 322, 331, 333, 4441, 4444, 12345, 987654321, 3610106226, 1010101010, 11111111111, 10812816208148888188, 82428208832101683082414123828341883888,3919555395539111955255533922519455392511539551925395511, 1515515551555515555515555551555555155555155551555155151, 999199999915999991599999999915999915999999919399999999991915999999999999999999999915999999929999999, 10121111011011011011011011011011011012110110110121101110110121111011123101101101101121011011110110111, 15101251011012229752519101110101010101010111111101101101101101111011011011011110111101101101101101915, 2020220202202022020220202232020220202202022020223220232020222220220222202202202202202202202202202202202220223202202202202202202202202222022022022022022022222202202202202202222022022022022022023876543213
```

Falsy

```
0, 2, 9, 10, 11, 23, 233, 4440, 50022, 50044, 1101010101, 11131111311, 121666626162, 181811818128181818, 127271272722672224724122727122712242722472727272722472727272247272127272, 1001023010023100160010010010010061110250100123001001001230061001010100102370100610016001001001110230, 1241242212412241241241241241241241241241241241141624124114241241241242612412412416241222412411424221241244124142412412144124, 108484298442981044294284942984429844294291042942942942849429429484284948429484842942942984104842984429429844298448429429429429429429429428494294294842942942948429428484942942942942984429429844284948429428494842849484284942942942942942984484294294284942942942942942942942942942910429429484294294
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), standard rules apply.

- Input can be given in any convenient method.
- Output any two different values telling if the number is lengthy or not lengthy.

Comment: I assume `2244668810121416182022` is falsy because you can't leave the leading `22` until the end?

Comment: @Neil  2244668810121416182022 is falsy because both 22 have to be removed first then the 0 remains at the end

Comment: Is `10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101` truthy?

Comment: @Jordan 101 digits? Yes

Comment: Would `1017654321` be truthy of falsy? Or it would have to be `1010654321` or `1010065432` to be truthy? I'm trying to understand how the overlapping works.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel matches can overlap, in your example there's no overlaps at all, anyway only 1010654321 is truthy

Comment: Maybe you can use a different example for the overlapping test case. Because even without overlap, `11111111111` is truthy, since removing `11` without overlap becomes `1`, which we can then also remove. You may also want to change "from it ( including overlapping matches )" to "from it, **_including overlapping matches_**", since it's a pretty big part of the challenge and makes it for some languages quite a bit more tricky.

Comment: @AZTECCO So, overlapping is just applied to repeated numbers, like `555` for the `55` digits of `3919555395539111955255533922519455392511539551925395511`? But doesn't apply to `1010054321` on the `100` for `10` digits?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `3919555395539111955255533922519455392511539551925395511` becomes `391939391119233922519439251153919253911` when removing `55`s (with overlaps) in the first iteration, which can be further reduced to a truthy result (aka empty result) eventually. And `1010054321` becomes `054321` when removing `10`s (without overlaps), which is a falsey result since there aren't any `6`s to remove in the second iteration.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Would the overlap rule apply to `1010154321`? You start by removing the `10`, so, it should remove `10` and `101`, leaving `54321` behind, right? If the overlapping doesn't work for `101` in `1010154321` and doesn't work for `100` in `1010054321`, does it only work for `55` because the digits repeat?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I think you're misunderstanding the term 'overlap', since `1010154321` when removing `10`s will become `154321` (without applying overlap rule). You basically want to first determine all positions of the length (including potential overlaps), and only then remove them. [Here a pastebin with some of the examples that maybe clarifies it a bit better.](https://pastebin.com/LyXDK7Q1)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you. That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen absolutely right, I thought it was just a clarification but actually 'overlap' is a big part of the challenge in fact I spent some time finding proper overlapping test cases. And the example is ambiguous or too poor.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel I changed the example hope is clear now, sorry for being not clear as needed

Comment: Is the "3610106226" example correct? It looks like the "2"'s get replaced with "3"'s (so "3610106226" => "366336" rather than the expected "366226").

Comment: @coltim oh.. Yes , fixed now. Thanks

Comment: You should commit the sequence to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) `1, 12, 21, 22, 123, 132, 133, 213, 223, 231, 232, 312, 313, 321, 322, 331` :-)

Comment: @jdt omg at this point I feel like I have to

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 16 bytes

```
+~`^.*
v`$.&¶
^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLLTsQwDLz7OxaEQFrF46TrfAF/sSoHDlw4IMSRz@ID@LEySdPHVt0VTuKZjCduG/Xj9fPt/UWHu4fnfnj67s/HR/nqD8f73x85H4ZBRSFQAUhMjNTIzYhmEmPUkmKpxiTZT12K1dVp0NABnRQyDtElKLvCtQMxOkPdxRHhVJw9gnZugYpGdne4RVqMTrGsOaVkuSw2I6LsLQNJcywyiVaHklbkM5OmMusaU8uXMJerXSVnPrCGpjUsdBY0W15qa@NFzDoalmtCuZhwa2JLZz7uYBcH0HDa1xugPbVjQD6lcmOt1XqMsXmDnd3Ww08TBI7dZFdU5lYCRnnGG3PqeKW6q/3HZtN/bH8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^.*
v`$.&¶
```

Replace the input with a Retina program that erases all overlapping occurrences of its length from it. (Replacing overlapping matches can do weird things in Retina but fortunately only if the matches are variable length.)

```
~`
```

Execute that program on the input.

```
+`
```

Repeat the above until no more erasures can be made.

```
^$
```

Test whether the input was completely erased.

Comment: [falsy cases](https://tio.run/##fVBLTsQwDN37HMMIgTSKXz2JcwJuMeosWLBhgRBLjsUBuFhxnCZN@TWO/fx7sfvy@Pr0fOXl5vZhXu7f58vpjt7mw@n4@UGXw7IEAmXiQMyEyWQiEQl0DgEoWsRSYT0GeeKqiMHRPkSOIFY7rqBu1PIJyRUQ7UIShFGjfqWkJKGdDVdUm206exuTKdPFiSWwSbSBAs7uWVlLFBgdc1gpUi3fUbBz27Q2mwBuHf8nLLb0ioa4/YvueR5b0UotHmhN7K5tqKKCrFIUh2IEKrnHaiRbyu2QL6LV0Yq116hYgw79jUwHmvwX5R4W3l31yNlfb2gw@N6lP1/7Tfqurf4L "Retina – Try It Online") checked, Retina worked well on this

Comment: @AZTECCO Whoops, I meant to include the falsy test cases too. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 42 bytes

```
''-:(#~1-]+./@(-@i.@#@]|.!.0"{E.~)":@#)^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTfb9MwEH7vX@GtEllFmvnOdmKnAkWg7WniAfGGyoQQ00BISPx4QEP918t35yRNSzvNse@@u/t8dhxfvm7TWeuatTW3BmMGi9b1WZuKYnZeFXfmRWsKUyLWYiwr8/rtzfW2KJbtxXxDy/Xz6rK7WHZfqm7erf9WZ5U9f7iqNovztpsvPrS328XszavK2FX3sL6Yr@bd/KF6v3j2cnOJYLeipRCvqrWynp52Nvv86f67Kd79@P3r/k@RrbtVdcvYbYF9bkxBpSEuDUMzC3alcWI5MZ0T5ODz3pNKryQfSpNiUwefyTVZsjVzjagdHuBdk0AkjlQztI9oFGNpInuOcEUkslRHZ@EhjzUiR@fBcaCWLlEKIbgkA@mgWWyXmAMlL24AUgYBqpZVAwXpOrLo5b4aw0rHxJSwpDYKU7WDo4OSS7vYlLjXRj/3Wg@L5XTsY50P4YizxW5vAvd6sPMhgB/6ecypCXJqfa7pk9vBFo5Yhxy8HG6QxXNUuBNeyD7EnN2jfqQPGU9Ej/qeQnPDjXZlMRTP9cdvP0/UDi44akS/olx1WE5Grha4grVSRFBaNeMZa104ykLKiWo0rlEasFAWpIKjqiiMhhsVqDAM9g1qhLNXh5eQb3h4djijPFl2ig2wg7Bya1Bw4tj1Wj4sB7VAGwICa8Vk@xRNpu@lIM0t@8XuPLNqxY91FHs9oIkf5zFaGucdqU/t1TFMIjX1P@Oj5xS9CLKi8I/xafRlD65/1pO49JiNmHEcOdFjQpzMH5LFSZp0KuU@lLx77GnOcfUBTRQfzor/r3asj@868HHDt/8A)

Handling overlaps made this awkward, and this was the shortest approach I could find.

Consider string input `'82428208832101683082414123828341883888'`.

The approach is to do the following until a fixed point:

- Find all matches `E.` of the length within the input.  This returns a boolean vector where the ones indicate the *start* of each match.

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  ```

  But we need to mark every position of each match....
- `-@i.@#@]` So we generate the numbers `0 1 ... <length of length>` (in this case just `0 1`) and then rotate our boolean vector right by each, creating copies of it:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  ```
- `+./` And sum the rows:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
  ```
- Finally we invert the mask and use that to filter the input:

  ```
  8242820883210168308241412283418888
  ```
- `''-:` Once the fixed point is reach, we just check if the final result is empty.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>90 ...</s> 65 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.gsub!(/#{n.size.to_s[/(.*)(.*\1)\2*/]}(#$2)*/){}?redo:n<?0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbbtswDH3fV3joHpLAS0RKsqlhWz8kDYYVa4c9LC2aFeiW5tuzQ8rXzAkmS@QheUTJsuin59vfx/tPx/eft/vt8vvu@fbtbHUFuPvx52756@HLbr2aLRdzjBua3/BitTnMrt7xfLGa7w/XT3ffHj5sP167w/GxWFNZEJcFQzMr9mXh1fJqeq/IwxdCIJPBSCGWRZK6iiGTK3LkKuYKUdc@wH3TgBALVQwdBI1EykI4sMAlSOSoEu/goYA1hMUHcDyopU@UYow@6UA6aFbbJ@ZIKagbgIxBgKZ11UhRu40sGjlWXdjomJgSlrRGcah62Dko@dTHhsRR6/zcaDss1tNxlzqfwg5ni/1oAje6tfMhgB@becypjnpqTa7hk9vJFiasUw5eDjfI4ZkU/owXsgkxZ3enL/Q245nopO9/aL690X6z/Pn1cf/68nq/frGS2hzeoFpwpVEV9t30csPyOnJ9wBWd07KBsjrpTtUqwVMWWkBUoXGFYoCFQiATLKZEGTXXJlBTGBxqVAVnr42goVBz@/Q4ozxZd4oNsIdwek9QYuroe6WfkqNZoLUBhZVhck2KOtNHKchy636xu8Bs2vCljvKuWjTw4zw6y@Lck5rUwRztJDLT/ixBAicJKsipwl8lpM6XPbjwWQ/i2iUbkrF0HAmYIIP5bTIZpEnnUo6h5h2xhzm71Vs0UHw6S/5dbap379ryJ@708S8)

#### How?

To replace overlapping occurrences use the following regex to split:

```ruby
/(.*)(.*\1)\2*/
```

This will always match the whole number that we are searching, but if some parts are repeated in an `ABABABABA` pattern, then the regex groups will capture A and BA. B will be empty if only A is repeated, and A will be empty if the pattern is not repeating.

So, now that we have captured `A` plus any number of occurrences of `BA`, we can use a new regex to find overlapping matches, we need to add `(BA)*` at the end:

```ruby
/#{n.size.to_s[/(.*)(.*\1)\2*/]}(#$2)*/
```

Repeat until there is nothing left to substitute, then check if the string is empty.

Thanks AZTECCO and Dingus each for -1 byte ideas which put together brought the byte count down by 3.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

-2  bytes from @Traws' improvement, -1 more from tweaking more

```
~#{x@i^/(#n:$#x)#[n~x@;]':i:!#x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#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)

Takes input as a string. If it is okay to return empty lists for "Truthy" inputs, and non-empty lists for "Falsy" inputs, 2 bytes can be trimmed (the leading `~#`).

- `{...}/` set up a converge-reduce, running the code in `{...}` until two successive iterations return the same value or the original input

  - `(#n)#[...;]':i` set up a stencil-apply, with a `(#n)` window size, applying `#[...;]` to each slice of `i`

    - `i:!#x` generate a list of indices of the input, storing in `i`
    - `(#n:$#x)` determine the string to remove, storing in `n`; calculate its length, and use that as the window size
    - `#[n~x@;]` filter each slice down to those that match the string to remove (`n`) (slices that do not match the string to remove become empty lists)
  - `i^/` remove those indices
  - `x@` index into the input, and (implicitly) return
- `~#` convert empty lists to `1`, and non-empty lists to `0`

Comment: you can save 2 bytes constructing the indices with a sliding window: `~#{x@i^/(n~/:x@)#(#n:$#x)':i:!#x}/`

Comment: Thanks! Building off that I was able to trim another byte with `~#{x@i^/(#n:$#x)#[n~x@;]':i:!#x}/`/

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 101 bytes

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>[...q=s.length+''].some(_=>s.slice(i--).match('^'+q))?'':c))?!s:f(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVXbjtowEH3fr0h5IdFCNh7biQ0K@9R@Qd9YWkWUW8XCLqGVqqrfTsczdkgooDrOzJkzFyeOB75XP6t6fti8HYe7/bfF6bQs63JSl2Vcl3V6WLxtq/kifkqfVoN4Ptgk5WSapuk7@raL3eq4fuz3Z2m9f13EXzEtrbcbDN8Mh0n6Wh3n67j/pf/4niTP/f5ojupDPVrGdXIaTx@mUU/0BijASSAMwIx0SjInmZSSLUk@pZTwWvkUpR2wpsi1Cqm5yESWA@QUk4WLrPNgpxFgRA6olcEhjHG8AQUGSYMlM5EbmSEjFK5nwEiFUdJwpLTCaq2ldTdWRQ3OlhZAC6scjUBQhEBImhfXQrtJNwsvu6pxUzilWovL0hC6rc6wIYSV9uxrB3ZGw4PXfu/AbVV2b8IlbDBbIDsJ4HWww1ZghvaZALbQbvd8tfbF4@IhrliXMfiCdNQyvK4KeYNF6V0ATDf6zgwVb3ivcv8TJsNBl71oNnDdRMeaesV/Mj7mxEqWoXfIpbOMWwuB76Jmc32HSMGCW0zkOCDHJiEbW0SQAEPKcFQBBQnsOrxBFdgvwCzdyrlUAeE6Y0aczG@AjwISReaODrafI84zd98WNFkYFhwO5oRF5ksUHN4pIag2PzM@oQIgTfjexObPA2rxuC@NRX44B/nSioiQJMj0vz3KKLBGOSEyp/BXR9mGYwa7gHXL76ZhwzA2TYxRmGBa@aGYaZWxt0p2oavbiW7XbFYPqKXgMsv8u9q12bxriMdj/jB7SJf7w8cK/1jiahBtkqicRL@j@X5X77eLdLtfxZvoOeq97Kafqm39a9aLRlFv@vnw47hGIxlHVVOgdrntTPfHlCTRn2R8@gs)

Or **92 bytes** by throwing an error if the input cannot be fully erased:

```javascript
f=s=>s&&f(s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>[...q=s.length+''].some(_=>s.slice(i--).match('^'+q))?'':c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVXNcpswEL7nKTQcYpg4BK0ESPE4ObVP0JvjdhhKEreOScDtTKaTZ3dXuxLGrpOpELvffvsjkLXmR/W76utu9by93LTfm93uft7Pb/rz8/u4T7vmeV3VTXyVXj1M43q6SuY3izRNX@Z9um42D9vHi8lkmfbtUxN/w6y0X68wfHV5maRP1bZ@jCdfJxcvSXI7mVzXSbKbLc4WIpLRFAU4CYQBmFFOKeYUk0qxpcintZZea5@icwesKYtch9RCZjIrAAqKycJF1n6w00gwsgDU2uCQxjjegAaDpMGSmSyMypCRGtczYJTGKGU4Ullp8zxX1t1YFTU4W1mAXFrtaASSIiRC0rx4LnM36Wbh5aEa3BROqdbisjRkPlZ7OBDSKrv3jQMPxsCD137vwG1V9tGEYzhgtkAdJIDXwQ5bgRm5zwSwZe52z1cbXzyOHuKEdRyDL0hHLcPrpFDvsCi9C4DpQX8wQ8V3vCe5/wlT4aCrSCynrpvoWFOv@J@MjzmximXoHXLlWcathcB30bC5vkOUZMEtJgscUGCTkI0tIkmAIWU4qoSSBHYd3qBL7Bdglm7tXLqEcO0xI07mN8BHAYUic0cH288R@1m43xZysjAsOBwsCMvMlyg5/KCEpNr8zPiEGoA04Y8mNn8R0IjHfRks8sM@yJfWRIQkSab/79FGgzXaCZk5hf862g4cM9gFrEd@Nw0bhrEZYozGBDPKD8XMqIx9r@QhdHUPosc1h9UDGik4zjL/rnZqDu8a4vGYny3P0vu2@1ThByWupmKViPmN@CPqdtO36yZdtw/xStyK6G6z@Fyt@9dlJK5FtPjS/do@opHMRDUU6Dl3272ixI8cOrsGyaj9Gc3Em6jpu9Uk6CVeRE3XtR37RguiE1PfEpyz3V8)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 144 bytes

```powershell
param($a)for(;($i=$a|% Le*)*($l-$i)){$a=-join$a[(($k=0..($l=$a|% Le*))|?{$_-notin($k|?{$a|% su* $_|% s*h "$l"}|%{$_..($_+"$l".Length-1)})})]}!$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZtb9owEP7Or8iQOyWsVPHZCbYmtEpV96lSp3XfqqrKWBh0FDoStEnAb2dnO84LParZju/uubsntoNPvKz@5Otili8Ww8lqnR/YdLw9vGTr7DlkWTRdrcOPIZuPWbY7C27yQTQI2WLI5lG0Zdl4@LSaL1l2H4bs1zi@uEBfExntPm3Z43C5KudL9BvLuIrNIGCPRhnMgj5b9Pe7M4wzyY8fjH1xky9/lrMhj/bYH/bvWHbY93qXYS/Adh5chn3ePw9Yud7kUQsDAgQqEoBMFwQqSAJBMghBxgqKV0rJaVjSa5MJgWs1ShN5Yo0pj3mcAqQUYew75Wwamao4KJ4CSqmwcaWIMAUSFMYoXF3MUyViRLjEnShQQmKSUGSi0FwnSSK0eXAJKMHYQgMkXEsDo8JtBEfVSnKlCU/MsI@bqrkrarcNp5i0xkXZxpO2aNQa4FroxtcO7LQah0rSHwnMR4jfGnCs1rqzQHQSoJLePnFuSJBURAB6lJiTr8jb3bWjNRHWcQxun7qWMXZyEidQnCsXgINr@cbwjCe8JPY/YcLfRurC24s2zRZFZ8cUqCmQk/nu871iFTRKwlhwSOokjgFOOFyNer0Y/7OgvVxwN5Fu4Ck2SLGwkH4sM9xOoKxQNMsIRnbCsocPyBEWHXCofaRxyRH43uhOc8n0F8CtgcApNncKa5oBmpGaXzkk1sIw7zBqanUeVxQjF96h4Jab3hPuQAJYafW3BlbY1GstHM@1tqwfmqCKWlrAJ3Fr0uegpJKglTQTj43AUi91jTkE64WTLb8ZyhnK6aqOURITVCvfk6kWjT5F2VUNbye6zVm/3WstAcdZ6vXbqFHv1ce3Tq4XBbvg82p9nU1mw9vvT/mkDLb2PFmZF@VVVuTnzsz/vqAz/xGM8Q@Sg9Z5sVmUCLxn0ya@Z533X@6uNkW5enakD5eO1bS7zWSSF0VgmGrWYf7bE9aB3ypGE1ize@dX93LLcpR33Vqqf4F17nv7wz8)

Takes the number as a `string`, returns `$true` or `$false`.
The timeout is caused by the "overlapping remove" that generates lots of strings in memory

So here is a version that does not timeout, calculating the array of characters to remove only once: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRtb9owEP7Or8iQOyVdQfHZCbYmNKRq@1Rp07pvVYUyZkY7WjqSapOA387OdpwEelRzHN/dc3dP/BLf0@qPWZcLs1wOZqu12bP5eLN/KtbFQ8yKZL5ax@9jdjdmxfYsujLnyXnMlgN2lyQbZsYx@zVOh0OE2oBk@2ETD@5Xd4@suGHT4ZAtbxP0leeLqM@W/d32bGPhmE3fWXt4ZR5/VosBT3Y9VoxD5gS5kYlNB4@rChGzS253b1ix3/V6k7gXYbuIJnGf9y8iVq2fTdLBgACBigQg0wWBCpJAkAxCkLGC4pVSchqW9NxkRuBajfJMnphjzlOe5gA5RZiGh3K2jUxVHBTPAaVU2LhSRJgCCQpjFM4u5bkSKSJc4koUKCExSSgyUWiusywT2r44BZRgbaEBMq6lhVHhLoKj6iQ504xntrvXD/V4KBq3C6eYtMZJucazrmjVBuBa6NbXDTxoDQ61pA8J7CGkr3U4VhvdWyAOEqCWwT6xb0iQ1UQAepTZna/Ju49vR3MirOMYXD51LVN8yEGcQHGsXQAebuQrPTCe8JLY/4SJcBupC@8u2rxYlgcrpkBNgZzM98f3glXQKAljwSGpszQFOOHwNerlZMJvQXu54H4g3cBzbJBjYSH9WGa4G0A5oWiWEYzcgGUPX5AjLDrgUfdK65IjCE@re80n0yeASwOBQ2rvFNY0C7Q9t385ZM7CsOCwau50ntYUIx9@QMEdN70mXIEEcNLpr3WssHnQOjjua2M5P7RBNbV0QEjizqT3QUklQStpB55agaVe6gbzCNYLLzt@25U3lNdVE6MkJqhOfiBTHRp9ivJQtbwH0V3O5utB6wg4zlIvv0b1Zq0hvrNzvSTaRp9W64/FbDH4/P3ezKpo4/aTVaasLovSXHjT/H1Cp/kRjSM29dDalM/LCoG3bN7G95zz5sv15XNZrR486e3Es9p2/TybmbKMLFPDOjC/A2ET@K1mtIENe3B@9R93LEd5HztTDR9wzl1vt/8H)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 114 bytes

```
StringReplacePart[#,"",List@@Interval@@StringPosition[#,ToString@StringLength@#,Overlaps->All]]&~FixedPoint~#==""&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8a6bcc18-5d29-4d03-82db-e10b84e883d0)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΔÐgU.sRXδÅ?XgGDÁ~}_Ï}d
```

Port of [*@Jonah*'s J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254637/52210).

Outputs `0` for truthy and `1` for falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JTDE9JD9YqDIs5tOdxqH5Hu7nK4sa42/nB/bcr//xZGJkYWRgYWFsZGhgaGZhbGBkARQxNDI2MLIwtjE0OghIWFBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##tVTNihNBEH6VYbwoNNJV3TNT7SUX0dseRGEhBIkaVkEQnLiQQwQPelXEh/ABxOuCc9@H8EWyX3XPb0zCXuzuqfqq6qvqnp@ad/XyxZvV7vIsf/r@w/r1Jnu0fFuvNvmds@Zn3lxld5ure9l6Va@zl8t6VT/IcrO53Mzy7O@X71k@2@yufzTfLp7dr5@cX/9qPs/OLx4/bD593D5vvm5f7cz2z@/Zbj4nQ2yYDDOAMw7QATsH7Zzx3pMKr1FfmCBVWXhlke1mhK3XldFgLg0NAwwhFioZ2gsGiRhhzwKPINFSKc7CQx4bCYvzoDi5PY0KKnTFK4lWTlUfjnScOFCA5YJeOCs0q@0Cc0HBqxuAIoMAoyYTAhLjoGKsBtg7KLgwxMbEyej93OrRM/6PU3dhfUv21OJ92ONksZskcKs7m/T9gF60acyhKvT5tqXGM429Exyw9jl4gIYt5kHhjngh2xBzcvf6xOoqHoke9N2G5rr@cgszt4aNfgRoJYPe5NSP1hQWXJXalqP3SOQoCXQrlRhcoucMod0oCpao0C1ccRUFWhUX@wpNxckbL68hX3E3B5xQSsbpsDc7CKufABpUHcMq9TVxES3QuoDCMmKybYkq0SclKNbGaXE2zxx1xKcW/g1lh0Z@PIveinEeSG1pHx1dEkVT/11ePAfxKsiqwh/Jh96XPPiUkx7FdUkyJGHpOeKRIKP8rpiMyoRjJadQ607Y45r97h0aKd7Pkn93O7T6e@34i8UN).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ         # Loop until the result no longer changes:
          # (using the implicit input-integer in the first iteration)
 Ð        #  Triplicate the current integer
  g       #  Pop one, and get its length
   U      #  Pop and store this length in variable `X`
  .s      #  Pop another one, and get a list of its suffices
    R     #  Reverse this list of suffices
      δ   #  Map over the list of suffices:
     X Å? #   Check which suffix starts with the length we stored in variable `X`
  X       #  Push the length from variable `X` again
   g      #  Get the length of that length
    G     #  Loop that length-2 amount of times:
     D    #   Duplicate the current list of 0s/1s
      Á   #   Rotate it once towards the right
       ~  #   Bitwise-OR the values at the same positions together
    }_    #  After the inner loop: invert all 1s/0s
      Ï   #  Only keep the digits in the integer at the truthy indices
}d        # After the changes-loop: check if what remains is a non-negative number
          # (resulting in 0 for the empty strings; 1 if any digits still remain)
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Unfortunately 05AB1E lacks a builtin to get all indices of a match (it only has a builtin `k` for the first index of a match). Otherwise the `.sRXδÅ?` could probably have been a bit shorter.

PS: Without having to deal with overlapping matches, this could be 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) instead: `ΔDgK}d`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
Ｗ⌕ＡθＩＬθ≔Φθ¬⊙ＩＬθ№ι⁻λνθ¬θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYy9CgIxEIR7nyLlHsQiWF4VBCsVXyHchcvCsiE/p/j064brnGKa@b5ZUqhLDiTySUjRwA159URQrLmG1uEeeesJyqQxvjXcWBnqsQ7kmTt4/sIfqm7euQNa80DeG5A1PB50KdN8elXUdcgKzyLOuYs7Ss5v@gE) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for lengthy, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⌕ＡθＩＬθ
```

While there are overlapping matches of the inputs length in the input...

```
≔Φθ¬⊙ＩＬθ№ι⁻λνθ
```

... filter out each character that matched at least one of the digits in the length.

```
¬θ
```

Output whether the input was lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>153</s></sup> <sup><s>142</s></sup> 137 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)

```c
char*o,*a,b[999];k;z;d;f(i,n){a=i;o=b;for(z=k=0;*a;a++)atoi(strndup(a,d=log10(n)+1))^n?k<1?*o++=*a:k--:(z=1,k=d-1);*o=0;z=z?f(b,o-b):!n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVV7b5swEP87fAoWqRIkoPrOBuww1A/SdRJ5dSgpVEmqSan61ZedX4RkaTVj3@N3Dxvjw4v0ebE4nRa/6t2kSyZ1Mn9USj2Vm/JYLst11CRt/F5XTdlV83Ld7aJjtalYOanLejqN60PXRPvDrl2@vUZ1sqy23TOwqI2nEMc/24fNd3iYdNNpNalnmzSdUTQkm2qZQlxOOspzrI4P62iedOk8nn1ry4/TS920URy8ByOzpvCw2h/2j09hFRI0ur8PD7u3FUljGCfhGFBTNDKiRbhm3GLcgpxbjRubEAIcF@PE5EIuMg0pWeSZ8ME5MGA5Ym4SM/8Y7dysUQJKyJG4kNRASpc6g0x3Myxx9JL1ZuMONliiQEk5Ja2IQS45IwQELVei5IIm4VJPNOYKFMVypQetiThqnSvEDJTQMAlgPIBEw90s9MFBmQbZkJ3FHgDF1dk2dLxoPY6Ou71ggHrH2Fcdr8VethryiwB03OvQbzvFZC4WURWZ3giXb/jYdrWMG9q1D72knQoZPTcJ/wQl6kyIFu75F91n/MR6E/sfN@7PPDfvQyW2rrd7U2PmqJsKUvaU26NvUG6pryhjyhizBUeCri3t7PfZVQ0HS2ytQk4Ncyoc99mocMAQlIZJ61dgYQjVIg0UBZUBWtQMoU2iQP@cZSvZYH8KaTnIiTB9lqiuNHDuuf7UmBmN3LxBi7mRgbkUhXW/SAEmt/@t0CoFouFG/qpTXedeGuC0O71m7Hh2cqmFAXwQGJVWoP9KQgpUUmgCTDP6oQjVYxahsrB8YNddWkVaWfY@UlCAHMT7ZHKQRn2W8lLUeS@8hzn72b00YHgdJf@d7Vbv39X7@1O/apcksGD0UQbBiO66MGraQ9jQ1cNKdw81T2XY0MUXjPRt9Lojh3U0vtvPwrvlj5bOqndLwnV0lumK3K7aHojjuKRpgo/g9Gex3tbP@1P6@5RuX/4C)

Comment: Nice work! You can save 4 Bytes by putting some initializations in arguments to built ins

Comment: @AZTECCO, thanks! I'm sure that there are some more bytes to golf here.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>117</s> 109 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)

```ruby
f=->s{a=*0...x=s.size
s.scan(/(?=#{x})/){a-=[*(y=$`.size)...y+x.to_s.size]}
s!=(x=a.map{s[_1]}*"")?f[x]:s>""}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vVFLDsIgEI3bnkLRRVstBcTWmFAP0pCKxiYu_EQ0oTY9iZsu9FB6GisojReQ4c1MZt5jAlxvx_OyqOv7-ZQH08c2Z0EiS8F8BCFUTEK5uaydJqzEzg3dOeuXqvJCrxQBS323YIOFpngNvRgqeNpnRsMrR_aYq5iAW3EoZZphXvkAePM8VXwmEwAqM_TZGR26eQrGEUYYRYREgDu6gttlS-gPZodN8OS9NYz7-N9g25pu5ZRSZI8iMYm1a-7XgNCYUExMVYO-WzQmX2tzkxkx4ObRvj_2Ag)

Comment: [Saved some ](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vVFLDsIgEI3bnkLRRVstBcTWmFAP0pCKxiYu_EQ0oTY9iZsu9FB6GisojReQ4c1MZt5jAlxvx_OyqOv7-ZQH08c2Z0EiS8F8BCFUTEK5uaydJqzEzg3dOeuXqvJCrxQBS323YIOFpngNvRgqeNpnRsMrR_aYq5iAW3EoZZphXvkAePM8VXwmEwAqM_TZGR26eQrGEUYYRYREgDu6gttlS-gPZodN8OS9NYz7-N9g25pu5ZRSZI8iMYm1a-7XgNCYUExMVYO-WzQmX2tzkxkx4ObRvj_2Ag) , output negated

Comment: @AZTECCO Nice work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 32 bytes

```
W&znz=sm*@zd.Amx>z-dklzl`lzlz;!z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P1ytKq/KtjhXy6EqRc8xt8KuSjclO6cqJwGIq6wVq/7/NzQ1NAUhMIYQUBKVgkuDlRsCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 26 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_ðZl)rÈhXÊs îS Y}Z kS}gUÊN
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=X/BabClyyGhYynMg7lMgWX1aIGtTfWdVyk4&input=IjExMTExNjY2NjYxIg)

Input is a string, output is an empty string for "truthy" or a non-empty string for "falsy". A version which specifically outputs "true" or "false" requires [just an added flag](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=X/BabClyyGhYynMg7lMgWX1aIGtTfWdVyk4&input=IjExMTExNjY2NjYxIg). All test cases can be run [here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=Ck49W1Vd&code=X/BabClyyGhYynMg7lMgWX1aIGtTfWdVyk4&footer=VSsiIC0%2bICIrIVc&input=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).

Explanation:

```
_ðZl)rÈhXÊs îS Y}Z kS}gUÊN
                         N # Starting with the input string as Z
_                    }gUÊ  # Repeat this process a number of times equal to its length:
 ð  )                      #  Find indices of this string:
  Zl                       #   The current length of Z
     rÈ         }Z         #  For each index Y apply this function to Z consecutively:
        XÊ                 #   Get the length of Z
          s                #   Turn it into a string
            îS             #   Replace each character with a space
       h       Y           #   Overwrite Z with that string starting at index Y
                   kS      #  Remove all spaces
```

[This](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=CspzCvBWIHLIaFbuUyBZfVUga1MKpVc/VzrfVw&input=IjIzNDU2Nzg5MTAi) recursive alternative is a little longer, but I figured I would include it in case it has more room to golf.